# QuickFinder QGIS plugin generates python errors

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have had no success setting up the QuickFinder plugin in QGIS to search project layers. Once I select the checkbox "Search in project layers" in the settings and create a new QuickFinder file, it gives the following error when trying to create a search.

I had the same errors on a Win7 (QGIS 2.10.1) and Ubuntu machine (QGIS 2.8.1). I uninstall/reinstalled the plugin, and I also installed from the extracted zip file without any luck.

Any ideas how to get this plugin up and running on QGIS 2.10?

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins\quickfinder\gui\projectsearchdialog.py", line 78, in process
>      ok, message = self.projectFinder.recordSearch(self.projectSearch)
>    File "C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins\quickfinder\core\projectfinder.py", line 230, in recordSearch
>      self.deleteSearch(searchId, False)
>    File "C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins\quickfinder\core\projectfinder.py", line 197, in deleteSearch
>      cur.execute(sql)
>   OperationalError: no such table: quickfinder_data
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.10.1-Pisa Pisa, d20c5b7
>
> Python path: ['C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing', 'C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins\postgis_geoprocessing', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\GeoCoding\libs', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\requests-2.0.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\lxml-3.3.5-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\gsimporter-0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\osgeo4~1\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', u'C:/Users/username/.qgis2//python', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs', 'C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Comment: How are your layers stored? I was under the impression it could only search through SpatiaLite database layers.

Comment: My understanding is that it indexes the layers to a SpatiaLite DB to speed up the search, but the layers can be any local layers. In my case I tried both shapefiles and PostGIS tables. Both attempts failed.

Answer (score 2):

The error is `OperationalError: no such table: quickfinder_data` in the file projectfinder.py.
If you look at the Python source code, you discover that, when you create a SQLite Database, `quickfinder_data` is a Sqlite [Virtual Table](https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) (file projectfinder.py)

```
def createFTSfile(filepath):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(filepath)
    sql = "CREATE TABLE quickfinder_info (key text,value text);"
    sql += "INSERT INTO quickfinder_info (key,value) VALUES ('scope','quickfinder');"
    sql += "INSERT INTO quickfinder_info (key,value) VALUES ('db_version','1.0');"
    sql += "CREATE TABLE quickfinder_toc (search_id text, search_name text, layer_id text, layer_name text, expression text, priority integer, srid text, date_evaluated text);"
    sql_unicode61 = sql + "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE quickfinder_data USING fts4 (tokenize=unicode61 \"remove_diacritics=1\", search_id, content, x real, y real, wkb_geom text);"
    sql += "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE quickfinder_data USING fts4 (search_id, content, x real, y real, wkb_geom text);"
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
         cur.executescript(sql_unicode61)
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
         cur.executescript(sql)
    conn.close()
```

And that the connection to the database is closed (`conn.close()`)

To use it, you need to first push the refresh button (to reopen the connection, [Quickfinder does not automatically refresh](https://github.com/3nids/quickfinder/issues/22)) but look also at [How to setup FTS3/FTS4 with python2.7 on Windows](http://How%20to%20setup%20FTS3/FTS4%20with%20python2.7%20on%20Windows)   which may pose problems